# Looking for a website that teaches Geometry and Algebra II

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, reference-request

I'm looking for a website that teaches Geometry and Algebra II greatly and emphatically. I'm beginning 9th grade in about a month and am trying to get a head start. I'm an extremely quick learner and hope to find one soon!

Comment: For the benefit of our non-US users, what are Geometry and Algebra II? (These terms are very specific to the US.) Anyway, have you tried Khan Academy?

Comment: I wish I knew how to teach greatly and emphatically.

Answer (score 6):

The following site is  very good (and contains much more than what you asked):

http://www.khanacademy.org/

Answer (score 4):

[MIT Open courseware](http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm) might have something.

Also, [videolectures](http://videolectures.net/) might have something too.

[These](http://www.uccs.edu/math/vidarchive.html) video lectures are wonderful (depending on the lecturer)

Answer (score 4):

These teach both:

- https://www.themathpage.com
- https://www.mathsisfun.com

Other options:

- https://cnx.org
- https://www.oercommons.org/courses/geometry-2nd-student-s-edition/view
- https://www.mathopenref.com
- https://www.geogebra.org/materials
- https://www.geogebra.org/m/z8nvD94T#material/JVc49sEa